# selector to extract value from table cell

Tags: css

I wanted to get the time value `15:43:42` from the table cell `<td class="ant-table-cell" style="">15:43:42</td>` . however the console test seems not exactly correct.

Which selector should I used and how to extract the value?

HTML:

```html
<div class="ant-table-content" style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;">
   <table style="">
      <thead class="ant-table-thead" style="">
         <tr style="">
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Date</th>
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Time</th>
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Model</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="ant-table-tbody" style="">
         <tr data-row-key="852db0ee-bbaa-4aa2-a1ee-60836c6b5980" class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
            <td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-selection-column" style=""><label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper"><span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span></label></td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-cell-with-append" style="">
            </td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell" style="">23/05/2022</td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell" style="">15:43:42</td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell">16000samplerate-60train-40test-v1-16k</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

The console result of `document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(4)');`

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83YzS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) selects *all* matching elements and returns always a nodeList and not a single element.
To select a single element use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then be very specific which element do you want select.
In your example you can do it that way

```
const tdNode = document.querySelector('tbody > tr td:nth-child(4)');
const text = tdNode.innerText;
```

and of course it would be easier if you can set a class on the desired element.

Comment: how to combine tbody > tr td:nth-child(4) and tdNode.innerText as one custom selector?

Comment: just combine it `querySelector(...).innerText` and have a look at some basics.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: thanks. got it document.querySelector('tbody > tr td:nth-child(4)').innerText;

Answer (score 1):

If you meant which JS selector you should use, then my answer is the following: Added a class to the desired td: `cls`.

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("cls");
for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    console.log(item[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-table-content" style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;">
   <table style="">
      <thead class="ant-table-thead" style="">
         <tr style="">
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Date</th>
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Time</th>
            <th class="ant-table-cell">Model</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="ant-table-tbody" style="">
         <tr data-row-key="852db0ee-bbaa-4aa2-a1ee-60836c6b5980" class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
            <td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-selection-column" style=""><label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper"><span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span></label></td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-cell-with-append" style="">
            </td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell" style="">23/05/2022</td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell cls" style="">15:43:42</td>
            <td class="ant-table-cell">16000samplerate-60train-40test-v1-16k</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```